# How to configure SSIS package to run store procedure with with undefined dates but depending on the last extraction

Tags: ssis

I have a challenging task and am a bit confused as to the best approach to create an SSIS packahe.
Basically, I need to create a package that sends three times a week a csv file whose data comes from the sql server to the SFTP folder. My idea is to create a job that will be scheduled to run 3 times pro week the SSIS package.
The data in that file should be from the last run to yesterday.
Steps I have already done.
1- I created a configuration table to register the sent files.
[image]

2- I did a procedure to convert sql data into csv, where I put dates as parameters like this:
[image]

Result:

[image]

3- I'm trying to create a package but I'm having trouble putting the say what are the  that the store procedure inside of package need to run. Basically when I run package it has to get the date of the last loaded and run the procedure from that date to yesterday. I don't know if these dates should be as parameters or variables in package and how to configure that. I need to add he data into to the file name like this file_20221010.csv

4- I have defined this variables:
[image]

And a dinamic procedure here:
[image]

But something wrong  because it does not seems to work:

[image]

Comment: Use and execute sql task to set the start and end date variables in the package.  They can look this up from the configuration table.

Comment: How? I create a two variables in SSIS and I would like tu run a store procedure between these to variavels in OLE DB Souce, but it is nor possible, I am freaking out.

Comment: This shows how to set variables with an execute sql task: https://www.tutorialgateway.org/execute-sql-task-in-ssis-single-rowset/

Comment: This shows how to set the parameter in an oledb source - so with the comment above, you have what you need: https://sqlsimplify.com/using-variables-in-ssis-ole-db-source-parameters/

Comment: I see but I need to do other thing.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution Steps:

1. Create a Variable Start Date and End Date. Assign the current datetime stamp to the End Date variable.
2. Create a Execute SQL task and map the output to Result Set -> Start Date Variable.
3. Now pass the Start Date and End Date variables as parameter mapping to the stored procedure Execute SQL Task.

Alternatively, you can run a query using Data Flow Task and export to CSV using Flat file connection manager and write a script task to upload the file to the SFTP.

Comment: Can you tell how the alternative solution works?

Comment: When I try to define parameters in OLE DB Source I have this error: Parameters cannot be extracted from the SQL command. The provider might not help to parse parameter information from the command. In that case, use the "SQL command from variable" access mode, in which the entire SQL command is stored in a variable. (Microsoft Visual Studio)
How Can I solve this?